# makefile macro taking arguments

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'd like to make something of my own like the `shell` macro where you can say `$(shell command)`.

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything online about how to do this.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please don't. Particularly if other people are going to be using your makefile.

Comment: Why would you want to? The `shell` command already exists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In GNU make you can do something like the following. Imagine you want to generate the `.h` and `.cpp` file names from a simple file name without extension to be added as a sources of some rule. You can write:

```
define h_and_cpp_sources
    $(1).h $(1).cpp
endef
```

This generates a Makefile macro that gets the first parameter as `$(1)`, second as `$(2)`, and so on. Then:

```
target: $(call h_and_cpp_sources,file)
...
```

This will construct the rule:

```
target: file.h file.cpp
```

Answer (score 6):

You should try with the [call function](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Call-Function.html) syntax.

It's not exactly what you want, but AFAIK there is nothing more elaborate than that.